# Beta iOS app distribution problems

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, diawi, ubertesters

I have an app ready and I want to test the beta in some external devices. I am using the correct bundle id and in the iTunes connect page I created a certificate , added the devices and then created an ad-hoc provision profile. I opened it on Xcode and then archive the app and export it. I used Diawi and Ubertesters for the app distribution but in both cases I get "Unable to download app". I am missing something ?

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the issue is connected to the device provisioning. Please make sure you've added your device UDID to the provisioning profile and sign your .ipa file with it. Once the newly signed up build is uploaded to Ubertesters, please try to install it on your device.